# Can we put two files with main() in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have client server code client.cpp and server.cpp both with main().
Server need to be executed first and remain alive till not uninterrupted.

server.cpp includes two cpp files that I have created:

```
#include "serverFunction.cpp"
#include "serverFunction2.cpp"
```

Both of this also include `serverFunction.h` .

How to write makefile for this? I have used pthread so -lpthread at the end.
Individually I compile in this manner:

```
g++ -o a LinServer.cpp -lpthread
```

I tried with this:

```
all: LinServer LinClient

LinServer:
    g++ -o a LinServer.cpp -pthread

LinClient:
    g++ -o b LinClient.cpp -pthread
```

But it gives this error:

```
LinServer.o: In function `main':
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x6dd): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x6e9): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
LinServer.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0xb3e): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0xb55): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
LinServer.o:(.eh_frame+0x7b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [LinServer] Error 1
```

Comment: unrelated, but you should not be including `.cpp`

Comment: **NEVER `#include` .c / .cpp FILES**.

Comment: @user174889 try changing `g++ -o a LinServer.cpp -lpthread` to `g++ -o a -lpthread LinServer.cpp`

Comment: What rule are you using for `LinServer.o`?

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please tell me what you talking about?

Comment: One of your errors is about `LinServer.o`. How do you build that? Also, there should be no spaces before `LinServer:` etc.

Comment: Note that your compilation that worked used `-lpthread` but the compilations that fail use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.  If one works and one fails, ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think that is  red herring. The errors are about `LinServer.o` etc, the makefile rules shown produce `a` and `b`, and the command line version produces `a`. So there is more to it than (currently) meets the eye.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Maybe...the question implies that the programs compile with `-lpthread`, in which case the `makefile` code would compile if the option was `-lpthread`.  The output names are `a` and `b` so that each time `make` is run, the programs will be recompiled since `LinServer` and `LinClient` are never created, but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: Have you written a server that uses `pthread` and that you can build without error? You should start with something simple that works, then build up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I dont want to use command line, I want only make file to do entire execution. I am very new to creating makefile do dont have much idea! There's also some header files and .cpp files which are included using "include" in the server.cpp file!

Comment: But if one mechanism works when you use it on the command line, that same mechanism will (probably) work when you use it in the makefile.  Does the method using `-pthread` (instead of `-lpthread`) work when you run it on the command line?  If it does not work, why do you think running it from a makefile will make any difference?  If it does work, then you probably have misled us with the information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You have specified the library incorrectly:</s>

```
g++ -o a LinServer.cpp -pthread
```

It should be `-lpthread`, not `-pthread` (the `-l` option means compiling with library).

Your problems are not related with having two main() functions, but the answer is - yes, you can compile two files with main() function in the same Makefile, but only if the files belongs to different output files (different binaries).

Your error messages look like there is something wrong with your linker settings or with your configuration of standard C++ library (the linker seems unable to see it).

Comment: No, `-pthread` is correct because it modifies the compiler's behavior in other ways than just linking in the library.

Comment: can someone please modify my makefile?